# angularjs with ace code editor - forcing the editor to execute 'onblur' when model changes

Tags: angularjs

I am using `angularjs` in conjunction with `ui-ace`, a library that has a directive for the popular `ace` library.

### [ui-ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace)

### [ace text editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)

I have made some modifications to the directive because I need it to work with `string[]`, instead of normal strings. Everything works fine except a strange situation when switching my core model. Here is how it is set up;

- There is a grid with objects from my database.
- When an item in the grid is clicked, the `$scope.Model` is populated with the information from the database
- This includes a property called `Scripting`, which is a `string[]`, and it is bound to the ace text editor.
- the editor's text is set to `$scope.Model.Scripting.join('\n')`
- this behavior is repeated in different ways in the editor's `onChange` and `onBlur` events.

Now, what is going wrong is that I have to actually click on the text editor to trigger the `onBlur` event before I click on an item in the grid. This has to be repeated each time, or the editor won't update. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here is the relevant code. I am going to link the whole directive, as well. The plunkr has everything needed to reproduce the issue, including exact instructions on how to do so.

## [Full Demonstration and Full Directive Live (Plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/rOxz2fyGpejODBqGfVMs?p=preview)

## Relevant Directive Changes

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '?ngModel',
    priority: 1,
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {

        /**
         *  Corresponds to the ngModel, and will enable
         *  support for binding to an array of strings.
         */
        var lines = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);

        /*************************************************
         * normal ui-ace code
         ************************************************/
        /**
         * Listener factory. Until now only change listeners can be created.
         * @type object
         */
        var listenerFactory = {
            /**
             * Creates a blur listener which propagates the editor session
             * to the callback from the user option onBlur. It might be
             * exchanged during runtime, if this happens the old listener
             * will be unbound.
             *
             * @param callback callback function defined in the user options
             * @see onBlurListener
             */
            onBlur: function (callback) {
                return function (e) {
                    if (angular.isArray(lines)) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(acee.getSession().doc.$lines);
                        });
                    }
                    executeUserCallback(callback, acee);
                };
            }
        };

        // Value Blind
        if (angular.isDefined(ngModel)) {
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(value) || value === null) {
                    return '';
                }
                else if (angular.isArray(value)) {
                    return '';
                }
                // removed error if the editor is bound to array
                else if (angular.isObject(value)) {
                    throw new Error('ui-ace cannot use an object as a model');
                }
                return value;
            });

            ngModel.$render = function () {
                if (angular.isArray(lines)) {
                    session.setValue(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel).join('\n'));
                }
                else {
                    // normal ui-ace $render behavior
                }
            };
        }

        // set the value when the directive first runs.
        if (angular.isArray(lines)) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(acee.getSession().doc.$lines);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you set up `ngModel.$formatters` incorrectly for your array case.

Try changing:

```
else if (angular.isArray(value)) {
     return '';
}
```

To:

```
else if (angular.isArray(value)) {
    return value.join('');
}
```

Personally I think it would have been easier to pass joined arrays in to model and not modify the directive. Then you wouldn't have issues with future upgrades

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MPoEDlwUonq6N86n1QB?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: How would you suggest passing in the joined array? I tried that first, but it was very slow.

Comment: I can't see why it would be slower than joining inside directive

Comment: Hrnm. You raise a good argument that I hadn't considered. Here is my logic - the way this is working uses the built in `doc.$lines` string array. The way you are suggesting, when I tried it, I was taking the contents of the editor and turning it into a string array when the content changed. This resulted in a new array being made each time you typed. This way, I only do that on blur.

Comment: Oh, to be clear, I do _need_ to store the content as a `string[]`. Storing it as a plain string isn't an option. This is specific to the way other parts of my program work.

Comment: So I guess my question is, is there a more efficient way to *1* load a `string[]` into the editor whenever needed and *2* turn the content of the editor into a `string[]` before the model is saved? The second part I can do in `onBlur`, but the first part is more difficult, as I don't have access to the editor within the directive that gets the model.

Comment: Alright, actually, this isn't fair. I had a problem, and you answered it. Thank you so much for looking at it! I will post a new question related to this specific thing, if that is okay.